# Multiple Events in one document

Tags: jquery, events

I have two Events, in one document, like this:

```
$qtyFields.on("keypress input", function(){
   // stuff happening
   $passengerAmount.trigger("passengerQtyChanged", [total]);
});

$passengerAmount.on("passengerQtyChanged", function (event, total) {
   // more stuff happening
   var ev = $.Event("keypress");
   ev.which = 13;
   ev.keyCode = 13;
   $(this).trigger(ev);
});

Event.observer(window, 'load', function() {
   // some stuff happening after window load
});
```

I am working on a Magento (1.9) webshop which sells boat trips. On the product page, customers can enter the amount of tickets they want to order (for example: 1 adult, 2 children). When people enter a number, passenger forms (a form where the customer can enter their personal information) appear, according to the amount of passengers entered. So, if they enter 2 adults and 1 children, 3 forms will appear.

- The `$qtyFields` are the input[type="number"] fields where people can put in their passenger amount.
- The `$passengerAmount` is the div where the forms are generated.

---

The amount of passengers can be entered in two ways:

1. Is to use the arrows up and down on the keyboard or click the arrows that are automatically in an `input[type="number"]`
2. Is to use the numpad or numbers on the keyboard

The first method works very well, no questions about that. But when I use the second method, the right price (passengers * passenger price) only appears when I hit enter after typing the number.

This is why I want let jQuery trigger a keypress for the enter button, so the price is updated everytime I enter a number via method 2.

The problem is, is that the keypress Event is not working. The loading Event (last lines) is working well, so I think the two Events are conflicting with each other. Is this the case? If  yes, what would be a fitting solution?

---

Simple version of the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="input">
     <input type="number">
  </div>
  <div class="passenger-forms">
     <!-- here be forms -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you may be creating an infinite loop with your event handlers - `passengerQtyChanged` raises a `keypress` which raises a `passengerQtyChanged` and so on. What exactly are you trying to do? What is `$qtyFields` and `$passengerAmount`? Seeing your HTML would also help here

Comment: Ill put some HTML next to it. I will also expand my explaination of what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: So use change or blur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer already, simply moved the Event to the on() function on top of the document:

```
$qtyFields.on("keypress input", function(){
   var ev = $.Event("keypress");
   ev.which = 13;
   ev.keyCode = 13;
   $(this).trigger(ev);
   // stuff happening
   $passengerAmount.trigger("passengerQtyChanged", [total]);
});

$passengerAmount.on("passengerQtyChanged", function (event, total) {
   // more stuff happening
});

Event.observer(window, 'load', function() {
   // some stuff happening after window load
});
```